# where clause with two months in different years

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, where-clause

I want select values from specified seasons of the year grouped by year. Seasons are as follows: 
December(year before), January, February: **Winter**,
March, April, May: **Spring**,
June, July, August: **Summer**,
September, October, November: **Autumn**

If i want to get single season grouped by year, my query for Spring, Summer and Autumn looks like this:

```
select avg(value) from table where month(date) between 3 and 5 group by year(date);
```

But i don't have idea how to achieve such a result for winter, where, for example, December is in 2017, and January and February in 2018. 
Grouping by year is very important. 
Thank You for help!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in`:

```
select year(date), avg(value)
from table
where month(date) in (12, 1, 2) 
group by year(date);
```

If you want the months to be "contiguous" so December, January, and February are in the same year, then add one month to the `group by`:

```
select year(date + interval 1 month), avg(value)
from table
where month(date) in (12, 1, 2) 
group by year(date + interval 1 month);
```

Comment: Second query is exactly what i wanted, thanks Gordon :)